# How to implement predictive word to form sentence via custom keyboard in swift 3.0?

Tags: swift, swift3

I am using `UITextchecker` to autocomplete words however, I would like to implement a `predictive` word suggestion so as the user can form a sentence like how the `iOS` predictive keyboard function works.

Does anyone know how to implement this?
Feel free to share your ideas.

Comment: use tableview to show autocomplete

Comment: I created a custom keyboard with 3 buttons above to show the autocomplete words but if I pressed any of the buttons, I want to show the next probable word just like how the default iOS keyboard does. @ShobhakarTiwari